# Can "whose" refer to things?

Tags: determiners

Is it entirely correct to use the adjective 'whose' when the grammatical subject is not a person but a thing? For instance,

> The first poem **whose** publication he ever sanctioned

Comment: I apologise, albeit I looked for similar entries and found none.

Answer (score 0):

It's not “wrong” but there are other ways to say it, e.g. *The first poem that he sanctioned for publication*.

Now, for *who* and *which* there's definitely a strong division for animate / inanimate.